# Does Cull the Weak from different demon hunters stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

If there are multiple demon hunters in my game running Cull the Weak, will the effect stack? Does it stack additively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other demon hunters definitely won't get the bonus as it is a passive skill which only affects you. The tooltip states

> Increase damage against Slowed or Chilled enemies by 20%.

Which implicitly states your damage. If it read "Enemies you Slow or Chill take 20% more damage" then it would apply to other players in your group.

However, if someone else slows or chills an enemy, you still do the 20% increased damage to that enemy since it doesn't state you have to slow or chill them, only that you are the sole benefactor of the passive skill.

From my experience [*Cull The Weak*](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/cull-the-weak) is one of the best in slot passives for the demon hunter, and pairs very nicely with [Elemental Arrow](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/elemental-arrow)'s cold rune.

If you were to use another source which added damage against slowed or chilled enemies, such as

[image: Cropped screenshot of Bane of the Trapped tooltip]

Then it would stack additively. So you would do 40% more damage versus enemies slowed or chilled, and 20% more damage versus enemies who had some sort of impairing effect. I also would highly recommend using this gem to pair with Cull The Weak.

Answer (score 2):

Cull the weak only applies to you. You gain 20% damage against any slowed/chilled enemy.